# Grouping the same groups

Tags: mysql

I have the following list of tables:

Table ***phrases***:

- id
- phrase (string)

Table ***words***:

- id
- word (string)

Table ***phrase_words***:

- word_id
- phrase_id

Table ***forms***:

- id
- form (string)

Table ***word_forms***

- word_id
- form_id

How to combine ***phrases*** into groups according to the complete match of the list of ***forms***?

For example (as how it looks like when joining all tables in a query):

```
SELECT 
   phrases.phrase,
   words.word,
   forms.form
FROM 
phrases
JOIN phrase_words ON phrase_words.phrase_id = phrases.id
JOIN words as ON words.id = phrase_words.word_id
JOIN word_forms ON word_forms.word_id = w.id
JOIN forms ON forms.id = word_forms.form_id
```

Phrase 1)

| Phrase | Word | Word form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| He told me a story | He | he |
| He told me a story | He | she |
| He told me a story | He | they |
| He told me a story | told | told |
| He told me a story | told | tell |
| He told me a story | me | me |
| He told me a story | story | story |

Phrase 1)

| Phrase | Word | Word form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| They tell me a story | They | they |
| They tell me a story | They | he |
| They tell me a story | They | she |
| They tell me a story | tell | tell |
| They tell me a story | me | me |
| They tell me a story | story | story |

Phrase 3)

| Phrase | Word | Word form |
| --- | --- | --- |
| She told me a story yesterday | She | she |
| She told me a story yesterday | She | he |
| She told me a story yesterday | She | they |
| She told me a story yesterday | told | told |
| She told me a story yesterday | told | tell |
| She told me a story yesterday | me | me |
| She told me a story yesterday | story | story |
| She told me a story yesterday | yesterday | yesterday |

Phrases 1 and 2 can be combined as their words have common forms. However, phrase 3 cannot be combined with phrase 1 and 2 since it has the word "yesterday", which does not have a common form with the forms of phrases 1 and 2.

As a result, I want to have a list of groups of phrases IDs, concatenated with commas:

| phrases_id_list |
| --- |
| 1,2 |
| 3 |

Thanks!

Comment: Can you create an [mre] which shows a minimal example for the 5 tables that you are introducing here?   (maybe a [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved half of the task (my source data structure can be easily obtained from OP's source data by one simple query):

```
WITH 
words_count AS (
SELECT p_id, COUNT(DISTINCT Word) cnt
FROM test
GROUP BY p_id
),
common_words_count AS (
SELECT t1.p_id p1_id, t2.p_id p2_id, COUNT(DISTINCT t1.w_id) cnt
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 USING (WordForm)
WHERE t1.p_id < t2.p_id
GROUP BY t1.p_id, t2.p_id
)
SELECT t0.p1_id, t0.p2_id
FROM common_words_count t0
JOIN words_count t1 ON t0.p1_id = t1.p_id AND t0.cnt = t1.cnt
JOIN words_count t2 ON t0.p2_id = t2.p_id AND t0.cnt = t2.cnt
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dae64c83a891d7549275115148597fd3)

For to continue I need in expanded source data with at least 3 groups, and there must present the groups with: a) one phrase b) 2 phrases c) over 2 phrases.

---

For not to lose: merging 2 groups into one. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0687175531f8fe1b9919c6c123474c32)